# How to build a jar from a module of maven with dependencies from other module?

Tags: maven

I have some modules in maven, and I want to build a jar of a module which has a dependency of just other module.

How can I include in the jar both modules?

Edit:

I have the followings modules:

```
  myproject-core/
    myproject-api/
    myproject-dependencie/
    myproject-api-web/
```

And I want to build a jar in myproject-api with myproject-dependencie. I have more dependencies in myproject-api and I only need to have in this jar myproject-api and myproject-dependencie.

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do here, can you clarify what you have, and what you want? Could you post some sample POMs to help maybe?

Comment: I edited with more details, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the maven-shade-plugin will be your friend:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

In you plugins section Something like:

...

```
    <properties>
        <shade-main-class>{your-main-class}</shade-main-class>
    </properties>
```

...

...

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
             <includes>
                <include>com/yourcompany/**</include>
              </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${shade-main-class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
```

Comment: Hi thelINtoy, with this code I think I will get a jar with all dependencies,but I don't want all the dependencies I just want one of them.

Comment: I think I can use exclude tag to exclude the rest of dependencies...but I have quiet a lot and I am looking for other way...

Comment: After you edited your question I have updated the answer to show you can use an include filter